# CSS Menu goes underneath slider

Tags: html, css, z-index

My site's navigation dropdown menu is hidden behind the featured post slider on my front page. I've tried changing the z-index value of the navigation li, ul, etc but can't seem to get it to work. I've gone as far as adding a z-index to every single css element that the navigation relies upon, but it still is under the slider.

Would appreciate any help.

Site: [Link](http://southerncrossdota.com/?preview_theme=scd2)
(The EVENTS dropdown)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easily fixed, with something like this:

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

`z-index` on its own is not enough, as it only works on an element with position other than `static` (hence `relative`, which won't cause any issues).

Comment: have you checked his site?? he has it in the css code it works fine in IE11 but the problem is with the chrome.

Comment: I did indeed check that code I posted worked before posting here. He has z-index, but not `position:relative`, which is also needed. And it's best to set these on the outermost parent (that is, the sibling of the parent of the content that needs to be overlapped).

Comment: sorry about that, i was checking his code for a long time your solutin worked fine , i didn't see the div nav there. my mistake, apologizes..